# Return data from combobox to textbox

Tags: c#, combobox, return, match

I just started C# a few weeks ago and wanted to know if there was any way to return data selected by the user from a combobox. I have already created a table I want the data to be returned from, for instance the user selects a value from the combobox, and I want that data to be matched from the table and returned to a different textbox, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the method that related to combobox item selection (I forgot the name), so that whenever user choose an item, it trigger your method and you can retrieve data from a table and any thing you want. Could you please try and give me feedback, because I have not been working with C# for a long time :)